# how to put html code into Excel cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to format a cell of Microsoft Excel 2010 using html values like this:

```
<b>test</b>
```

Excel show it exactly like i wrote. But i want only the word **test**  in bold style.

I tried with paste special, but didnt found an HTML option. I also tried with some macros i found on internet, but nothing works.

Comment: Excel threats "<b>test</b>" as text. If you want to set a cell to bold using VBA you need `Cell.Font.Bold = True`.

Comment: Deleted my answer as my assumption that it worked was incorrect ... I just tested it ... nevertheless, you should be able to do something with regards to converting HTML to RTF, which can then be pasted into an Excel cell.